# Где корень?

Tags: морфемы

Интересно, есть ли корень в слове "их"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот что я нашла в Грамматике - 80.

*§ 1282. Местоимение третьего лица он (он, она, оно – в ед. ч. и они – во мн. ч.) изменяется по смешанному склонению, объединяющему в себе падежные флексии существительных и прилагательных. Основы форм ед. и мн. ч. местоимения он (за исключ. форм с предлогами, см. ниже) выступают в двух вариантах: в ед. ч. |он|- – в им. п. и |j|- – во всех остальных падежных формах; во мн. ч. |он'|- – в им. п. и |j|- – во всех остальных падежных формах.
   Примечание. Фонема |j| основы в формах с гласной |и| в начале флексии (формы тв. п. ед. ч. муж. и сред. р. и род., вин., дат. и тв. п. мн. ч.) фонетически не реализуется.
   При объединении с предлогом формы косв. над. ед. и мн. ч. местоимения он (она, оно, они) получают вместо начальной фонемы |j| фонему |н'|-, образуя так называемые "припредложные формы": от него, к ней, с ним; между ними. Формы предл. п. ед. и мн. ч., не употребляющиеся без предлога, всегда имеют в начале основы |н'|-: о нем, при ней, в них.
   Флексии падежных форм ед. и мн. ч. местоимения он (она, оно, они) в им. п. ед. ч. для всех трех родов – те же, что и флексии сущ. первого и второго скл. (см. § 1175, 1184). В им. п. мн. ч. форма они имеет флексию -|и| при основе на |н'| – он-и. В формах косв. пад. муж.-сред. р. ед. ч. и в формах мн. ч. при основе |j| выступают то же флексии, что и в прилагательных адъективного скл. (см. § 1310), формы род. и вин. п. жен. р. имеют флексию -|ejo| при основе |j|.
   Фонемный состав флексий местоимения он (она, оно, они) следующий: ед. ч.: им. п. Ж, -|о|, -|а|; род. п. -|ово|, -|ejo|; дат. п. -|ому|, -|ej|; вин. п. -|ово|, -|ejo| (-|ej|); тв. п. -|им|, -|ej| (-|ejy|), предл. п. -|ом|, -|ej|; мн.ч.: им. п. -|и|, род. п. -|их|, дат. п. -|им|, вин. п. -|их|, тв. п. -|им'и|, предл. п. -|их|.*

Если я правильно поняла, в местоимении *их* должна быть основа Й и окончание ИХ. Но Й - не произносится. По факту получается только окончание, а корень - нулевой (бывает ли такое?), так как в других формах он есть - /Й/